# What does SoC stand for?

Tags: terminology

… and no, I do not mean System-on-a-Chip.

I stumbled upon [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/46524/39208) which was using the acronym in the context of graphics, and found myself wondering about its meaning. Neither the question nor the answer further explained the acronym, and a search on google only got me "system-on-a-chip", which I was already familiar with, and "security operations center", which I was less familiar with.

What does SoC stand for in the context of game development (and/or software engineering)?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It stands for [Separation of Concerns](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), i.e. designing a software so that each section has a specific purpose.

As you guessed, it's a general software engineer priciple and it is not specific to game design/programming.

This is often done (and not limited to) to reduce the coupling between sections, resulting in better reusability, code clarity and (sometimes) teamwork.

Comment: Additional benefits: test-ability and composition

Comment: It's not necessarily a software thing though, it's often a network engineering thing too. Things like not having your MMORPG on the same server as your billing system and registration page for example, that's SoC too.